# Django - matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django project and I'm getting this error, "State matching query does not exist." why is this happening? the state is in the model store, can you explain me this error and how to solve it?

Thanks. 
Views:

```
def Test(request):
    stores = Store.objects.all()

    data = []

    for store in stores:
        data.append({
            'id': store.id,
            'name': store.name,
            'address': store.address,
            'state': store.state,
        })

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), 'application/json')
```

Models:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Traceback:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.o.o.1:8000/posts/Test/
>
> Django Version: 1.7.1 Python Version: 2.7.6 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'clients', 
>   'cobrands',  'core',  'posts',  'bootstrapform',  'rest_framework')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/home/tabzz/c-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/tabzz/c/posts/views.py" in Test
>     34.             'state': store.state, File "/home/tabzz/c-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py"
>   in **get**
>     572.                 rel_obj = qs.get() File "/home/tabzz/c-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in get
>     357.                 self.model._meta.object_name)
>
> Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /posts/Test/ Exception Value: State
>   matching query does not exist.

Comment: please post your errormessage/stacktrace, thx :)!

Comment: are you sure this error is being generated when hitting the Test view and not a different one? Usually this error pops up with a Store.objects.get() query.

Comment: im sure, Jingo, there's the stacktrace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a Store model in your database that does not have a `state`. When you try to access `state` here:

```
data.append({
    'id': store.id,
    'name': store.name,
    'address': store.address,
    'state': store.state,
})
```

Django throws an error because `state` is a `ForeignKey` on `Store` and it has to look it up when you access it with `store.state`. If `state` is empty and you haven't set your `ForeignKey` to allow `None` values with `null=True`, Django will raise a `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: I see, thanks, now i have this problem. 
"<State: New york> is not JSON serializable"

Comment: i print "data" and it save states like this "'state': <State: New york>" how do i only save "new york"? :S

Comment: @Tabbz you need to use `'state': store.state.name` instead